# Construct a class and run methods from command line in php

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I am trying to run construct a class and run a function from that instance form CLI like so:

```
php -r "include 'User.php'; new User(1111); returnId(); "
```

throguh some testing i have figured out that the class instance is being created, but returnId gives me call to an undefined function  but it's defined in the class

Here's my full code snippet:

```
include('UserRecord.php');
class User implements UserRecord{
    protected $firstName;
    protected $lastName;
    protected $dob;
    protected $_id;
public function __construct($userNumber){
        $this->connectAndGetData($userNumber);

    }
        function returnId(){
          echo $_id;
        }
function connectAndGetData($userNumber){
        $serverName = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $username, "", "db");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)){
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  _id, last, first, dob FROM user WHERE un = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $userNumber);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $this->firstName = $row['first'];
            $this->lastName = $row['last'];
            $this->dob = $row['dob'];
            $this->_id = $row['_id'];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `returnId()` is a method of `User` class, so you need to call it in the object of `User` class like this:

```
include 'User.php'; 
$user = new User(1111);
$user->returnId();
```

Ok, your problem here is as said above, `returnId` is a method of class `User` and so is `$_id`, you need to access it using `$this->_id` as you do in the `connectAndGetData` method.

```
include('UserRecord.php');
class User implements UserRecord{
    protected $firstName;
    protected $lastName;
    protected $dob;
    protected $_id;
    public function __construct($userNumber){
        $this->connectAndGetData($userNumber);

    }
    function returnId(){
      echo $this->_id;
    }
...
```

Comment: this gives me
`Notice: Undefined variable: _id in...`

Comment: Well, then I suggest you go read the basis about PHP [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) because you seem not to understand the basis about scope in PHP.

Comment: So, did you just recommend something that wasn't going to work?

Comment: No, I just realized that it's pointless to try answer your problem when you seem not know anything about OOP and scope in the first place. Do your research first.